# Javascript relative path from file name (without windows.location)

Tags: javascript, ajax

let's assume i need to make an AJAX request using a relative path from a filename without using `windows.location` (due to customer specific request).

So, on an hypotetical page: `mywebsite/myfolder/mypagename`, I need to do something like:

```
$.get( "./data/mydata.json", function( data ) {
  ....
});
```

doing so the request points to: `mywebsite/myfolder/data/mydata.json`, but i need it to points to: `mywebsite/myfolder/mypagename/data/mydata.json`

Is there any way to do it? i also tryed `"~/data/mydata.json"` but seems to work as `"./data..."`

Comment: I don't think you can do it without using windows.location

Comment: can't use windows.location due to customer request. It has some SAST consequences and the customer doesnt want to use it.

Comment: so use a relative path like you do for images, CSS, JavaScript etc....

Answer (score 0):

As what i'm asking seems not possible, i'm using windows.location.pathname with a validation regex on the url before sending any ajax call:

```
if (! ( /([<>]|javascript:)/.test(decodeURIComponent(apiUrl)) )) {

    ... do the call

} else {

    window.location.href = '/404';

}
```

Hope it might help others

Comment: How does this answer your original question?

Comment: It doesnt. It's a walkaround: I made my customer accept using windows.location but i do a check on the url to prevent any js written on the url from being processed. 
So if someone call a page like that: /mypage/<script>alert('i will hack you')</script> the regexp redirects to 404.

Comment: I am not sure how XSS will effect you with that... and I still wonder why you can not use a relative path.